# CXCallObserver - Monitor In Background

Tags: ios, callkit

I need to monitor in my app which interacts with BLE when a user is on the phone or not due to a limitation with some devices and BLE. I've written a basic call observer to test - but when the application is backgrounded it is not receiving any updates. I was wondering if anyone knew how to get call status notifications in the background?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{  
  @IBOutlet weak var callStatusLabel: UILabel!  
  var callObs : CXCallObserver!  

  override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()  
    /  
    callObs = CXCallObserver()  
    callObs.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)  
    print("Monitoring Calls")  
    callStatusLabel.text = "Monitoring..."  
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow  
  }  
  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {  
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()  
    /  
  }  

}  
extension ViewController : CXCallObserverDelegate  
{  
  func callObserver(_: CXCallObserver, callChanged: CXCall)  
  {  
    if(callChanged.hasEnded)  
    {  
      print("Call Ended")  
      callStatusLabel.text = "Call Ended"  
      self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green  
    }  
    else if(callChanged.hasConnected)  
    {  
      print("Call Connected")  
      callStatusLabel.text = "Call Connected"  
      self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red  
    }  
  }  
}
```

I currently have the following Background modes enabled:
Audio, AirPlay & PIP
Loc Updates
VOIP
External accessory comm
Uses BLE
Background Fetch

Comment: Did you solve this, I have exactly the same question?